# How can I make datetime input display date, ignoring client's locale?

Tags: angularjs, html, datetime

I have `<input type="datetime-local" ng-model="StartDateTime"/>`.
If have *GMT+3* on client machine and enter `01.01.2016 03.00.00` to the input, my `$scope.StartDateTime` equals to `01.01.2016 00.00.00`. I don't like it, I want my input to deal with real `$scope.StartDateTime` value, ignoring client's locale. I want it to show real *UTC* Date and Time. How can I fix that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this one. https://plnkr.co/edit/dQEqJivih4i9joCbc54f?p=preview

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('DateCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.currentDate = new Date('01-01-2016 03:00:00');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="DateCtrl">
    <div>{{currentDate | date:'d MMMM yyyy' : 'UTC'}}</div>
     <div>{{currentDate | date:'d MMMM yyyy'}}</div>
  </body>

</html>
```